# Delete folder in Amazon S3 using PHP with regex to exclude files

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm trying to delete a folder on an S3 bucket using `deleteMatchingObjects()` ([docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3ClientInterface.html#_deleteMatchingObjects)). I want to delete by a folder's prefix, but exclude any files (i.e any key that contains a `.`).

Here's my attempt:

`$this->s3Client->deleteMatchingObjects($bucket, $directoryPath, "/^[^.]+$/");`

where `$directoryPath` is `MY_FOLDER_NAME`, and the directory I want to delete is called `MY_FOLDER_NAME-finished`.

It seems the use of a prefix and a regex does not work as my folder is not deleted, but the string matches the regex pattern. Does anyone know if it's possible to use prefix and regex for this s3 method?

Comment: Couldn't you just add the prefix into the regex.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't match, `$this->s3Client->deleteMatchingObjects($bucket, null, "/^{$directoryPath}[^.]+$/");`

Comment: If the path includes any regex patterns, it could fail - try using `preg_quote($directoryPath)` to escape any special charachters.

Comment: I did try that, and using preg_match it matches correctly: `dd(preg_match("/^{$directoryPath}[^.]+$/", "MY_FOLDER_NAME-finished"));`  => `1`, but when I pass the same regex and `directoryPath` into the method, it doesn't delete the object.